# where isAzuer Devops path of build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Where is "/home/vests/work/1" in Windows 10 on my HDD? I can't find the path after the pipeline's build. Because I want to see a and b and s folders. I want to see folders in the blow path: Structure of work folder of this pipeline

Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory: echo /home/vsts/work/1/a echo

Build.BinariesDirectory: echo /home/vsts/work/1/b echo

Build.SourcesDirectory: echo /home/vsts/work/1/s

Comment: Are you asking about where the path of an installed Azure DevOps agent on a Windows 10 Or is it something else, please clarify?

Comment: If this is a question about Azure Pipelines, please ensure your question is tagged appropriately and include details such as whether you're using a self-hosted agent or a Microsoft-hosted agent.

Comment: i  run this script  after build task in yaml:- script:  
   echo "Structure of work folder of this pipeline:"

   echo "Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory:" 
   echo "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
   echo "Build.BinariesDirectory:" 
   echo "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)"
   echo "Build.SourcesDirectory:"
   echo "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is "/home/vests/work/1" in Windows 10 on my HDD? I can't find the path after pipeline's build.

If you want to see a and b and s folders in Windows 10 on your HDD, you should create a private agent for yourself:

[Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops)

Then use this private agent as build agent when you configrate your pipeline:

[image]

Now, you could see a and b and s folders in Windows 10 on your HDD.

The path mentioned in your question is the path of the ubuntu system.

Comment: thanks...yes...it's  true....and  it  save  in _work  directory  if clean option set to false.